# Can I post a comment with a link to my plugin?

Tags: discussion, spam

Say a user posts a question related to, in my case, downloading and parsing jsons in Unity. Am I allowed to post a comment saying something like "This problem is actually quite complex and hard to do right, so I made a plugin you might be interested in: (link)", or is it spam? If only SO had direct messages I'd go with those but sadly, this is not the case...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, that's spam. If you have a solution to a problem, post a complete answer that illustrates how to use it.

> If only SO had direct messages I'd go with those but sadly, this is not the case...

That is exactly why SO does not have direct messages.

Comment: In that case, a complete answer would contain disclosure and some example code on how to use the plugin in OP's situation.

Comment: @Kyll so can I ask in the comment if they're interested in using external tools, and if they confirm, post an answer showing how to integrate my plugin with their project?

Comment: You may want to change your mindset a bit in that case: Is your plugin likely to help **future readers** in a similar situation? If so, by all means, go for a complete answer.

Comment: Meh, if it comes up naturally, it's not bad.  If @Dunno searches for every relevant question and leaves 10s, 100s of comments... spam.